# Why does my base64 image have <!Doctype html> inside it?

Tags: java, html, jsp, bufferedimage

I'm trying to show multiple images on my `jsp` using this code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", baos);
                        baos.flush();
                        byte[] imageInByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
                        baos.close();
                        String b64 = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageInByteArray);
                        out.println("<td><img src=\"data:image/jpg;base64, " + b64 + "\" "
                                + "class=\"img-responsive\" "
                                + "width=\"304\" height=\"236\"/></td>");
```

But in the browser I get an error that says:

> GET data:image/jpg;base64,
>   /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgK…FMAooooAWkoooAa3SozRRTASgUUUALRRRQAUUUUCH9qZRRQAlFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFAH/9k=
>   net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Then I checked out the error using google developers tool and found this:
[image]

That Doctype tag seems to be inside my base64 String...
And I tried to remove that tag, along with the newlines, the image did show up. But sometimes, when I change the image, the Doctype tag seems to be at another part of the page like this:

[image]

I'm using Netbeans 8.0 and Apache tomcat 8.0

Can someone help me with this issue?

Edit:

This is a custom page to make a dynamic form that automatically generate form based on the elements (the insMap variable). My code is kinda messed up, because i'm still testing the page..., some suggestion would be good though.

My full code:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : CallFOrm
    Created on : Dec 1, 2015, 12:39:03 AM
    Author     : Darkside
--%>

<%@page import="javax.imageio.ImageIO"%>
<%@page import="java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream"%>
<%@page import="SimpleKubraLib.Misc.ImageOperation"%>
<%@page import="java.awt.image.BufferedImage"%>
<%@page import="Connection.Connection"%>
<%@page import="SimpleKubraLib.Conn.DML.MySQL.DataRetrieve"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.LinkedHashMap"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Map"%>

<%!
    private List<Object[]> getDataRef(java.sql.Connection conn, String colRefs[]) {
        String sql = " select " + colRefs[0] + ", " + colRefs[1] + " "
                + " from " + SimpleKubraLib.Misc.StringOperation.getSchemaTableName(colRefs[0]) + " ";
        return new DataRetrieve().getData(conn, sql, 2);
    }
%>
<h1 class="text-center"><%= request.getAttribute("PageTitle")%></h1>
<div style="display:none" id="FormAlertHeader" class="alert alert-danger text-center">
    Mohon periksa input anda!
</div>
<form method="post" action="../Form/FormHandle" class="form-horizontal" role="form"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <%
        Object mode = request.getParameter("FormMode");
        if (mode == null) {
            mode = "insert";
        }

        mode = SimpleKubraLib.Misc.StringOperation.replaceWord(mode.toString(), "_");

        Map<String, Object[]> insMap = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object[]>) request.getAttribute("insMap");
        Object labClassSize = request.getAttribute("LabelClassSize");
        if (labClassSize == null) {
            labClassSize = "col-xs-2";
        }
        Object inpClassSize = request.getAttribute("InputClassSize");
        if (inpClassSize == null) {
            inpClassSize = "col-xs-2";
        }

        String labClassSizeOffset = labClassSize.toString();
        labClassSizeOffset = labClassSizeOffset.substring(0, labClassSizeOffset.indexOf("-", 4) + 1)
                + "offset" + labClassSizeOffset.substring(labClassSizeOffset.lastIndexOf("-"), labClassSizeOffset.length());

        for (Map.Entry ent : insMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = ent.getKey().toString();
            Object[] vals = (Object[]) ent.getValue();

            Object realVal = (vals[1] != null ? vals[1] : (vals[8] == null ? null
                    : (SimpleKubraLib.Misc.StringOperation.getDeffVal(vals[8].toString()))));
            String tipe = vals[2].toString().toString();
            if (tipe.equals("select")) {
                if (vals[5] != null) {
                    tipe = "mul";
                } else if (vals[3] != null) {
                    tipe = "enum";
                }
            } else if (tipe.equals("file")) {
                if (vals[7] != null && vals[7].toString().equals("image")) {
                    tipe = vals[7].toString();
                }
            } else if (tipe.equals("number")) {
                if (vals[3] != null) {
                    tipe = vals[3].toString();
                }
            }
            boolean en = vals[9] == null ? true : Boolean.parseBoolean(vals[9].toString());
//            (vals[4] != null && vals[4].toString().equals("pri") ? false : ))
//            out.println(vals[4] + "<br>" + vals[8] + "<br>" + mode + "<br>");
            en = ((vals[4] != null && vals[4].toString().equals("pri")
                    && vals[8] != null && !vals[8].toString().equals("")
                    && mode.toString().equals("Insert"))
                    || (vals[4] != null && vals[4].toString().equals("pri")
                    && mode.toString().equals("Update"))
                    ? false : en);

//            <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
//  <label class="control-label" for="inputError2">Input with error</label>
//  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError2" aria-describedby="inputError2Status">
//  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
//  <span id="inputError2Status" class="sr-only">(error)</span>
//</div>
            // maxlength="10"
            if (vals[2].toString().equals("text")) {
                out.println(""
                        + "<div id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "div\" "
                        + "class=\"form-group\">"
                        + " <label class=\"" + labClassSize + " control-label\">" + vals[0] + "</label>"
                        + " <div class=\"" + inpClassSize + "\">"
                        + "     <input class=\"form-control\" id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "\" "
                        + "     name=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe
                        + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + vals[4] + "\""
                        + "     type=\"" + tipe + "\" value=\"" + (realVal == null ? "" : realVal) + "\" "
                        + "     " + (en ? "" : "disabled") + " "
                        + "     " + (vals[6] == null ? "" : "maxlength=\"" + ((int) vals[6]) + "\"") + ">"
                        //                        + "     <span  class=\"help-block\">Please correct the error</span>"
                        + "     <span style=\"display:none\" "
                        + "     id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "icon\" "
                        + "     class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback\" "
                        + "     aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>"
                        + " </div>"
                        + "</div>");
            } else if (vals[2].toString().equals("date")) {
                out.println(""
                        + "<div id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "div\" "
                        + "class=\"form-group\">"
                        + " <label class=\"" + labClassSize + " control-label\">" + vals[0] + "</label>"
                        + " <div class=\"" + inpClassSize + "\">"
                        + "     <input class=\"form-control\" id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "\" "
                        + "     name=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe
                        + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + vals[4] + "\""
                        + "     type=\"" + tipe + "\" value=\"" + (realVal == null ? "" : realVal) + "\" "
                        + "     " + (en ? "" : "disabled") + ">"
                        + "     <span style=\"display:none\" "
                        + "     id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "icon\" "
                        + "     class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback\" "
                        + "     aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>"
                        + " </div>"
                        + "</div>");
            } else if (vals[2].toString().equals("textarea")) {
                out.println("<div id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "div\" "
                        + "class=\"form-group\">"
                        + " <label class=\"" + labClassSize + " control-label\">" + vals[0] + "</label>"
                        + " <div class=\"" + inpClassSize + "\">"
                        + "     <textarea class=\"form-control\" "
                        + "     id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "\" "
                        + "     name=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe
                        + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + vals[4] + "\""
                        + "     " + (en ? "" : "disabled") + " rows=\"3\">" + (realVal == null ? "" : realVal) + "</textarea>"
                        + "     <span style=\"display:none\" "
                        + "     id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "icon\" "
                        + "     class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback\" "
                        + "     aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>"
                        + " </div>"
                        + "</div>");
            } else if (vals[2].toString().equals("file")) {
                if (vals[7].toString().equals("image")) {
                    if (realVal != null) {
                        BufferedImage bi = ImageOperation.convertToBi(realVal);
                        if (bi != null) {
                            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", baos);
                            baos.flush();
                            byte[] imageInByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
                            baos.close();
                            String b64 = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageInByteArray);
                            out.println("<td><img src=\"data:image/jpg;base64, " + b64 + "\" "
                                    + "class=\"img-responsive\" "
                                    + "width=\"304\" height=\"236\"/></td>");
                        }
                    }

                    out.println(""
                            + "<div id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "div\" "
                            + "class=\"form-group\">"
                            + " <label class=\"" + labClassSize + " control-label\">" + vals[0] + "</label>"
                            + " <div class=\"" + inpClassSize + "\">"
                            + "     <div class=\"fileinput fileinput-new\" data-provides=\"fileinput\">"
                            + "         <div class=\"fileinput-preview thumbnail\" data-trigger=\"fileinput\" "
                            + "         style=\"width: 200px; height: 150px;\">"
                            + "         </div>"
                            + "         <div>"
                            + "             <span class=\"btn btn-default btn-file\">"
                            + "                 <span class=\"fileinput-new\">Select image</span>"
                            + "                 <span class=\"fileinput-exists\">Change</span>"
                            + "                 <input type=\"file\""
                            + "                 id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "\" "
                            + "                 name=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe
                            + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + vals[4] + "\" >"
                            + "                 <input type=\"hidden\""
                            + "                 id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "b64\" "
                            + "                 name=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "b64"
                            + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + vals[4] + "\" "
                            + "                 value=\"" + (realVal == null ? "" : realVal) + "\">"
                            + "             </span>"
                            + "             <a href=\"#\" class=\"btn btn-default fileinput-exists\" "
                            + "             id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "href\" "
                            + "             data-dismiss=\"fileinput\">Remove</a>"
                            + "     <span style=\"display:none\" "
                            + "     id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "icon\" "
                            + "     class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback\" "
                            + "     aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>"
                            + "         </div>"
                            + "     </div>"
                            + " </div>"
                            + "</div>"
                    );
                } else {
                    out.println(""
                            + "<div id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "div\" "
                            + "class=\"form-group\">"
                            + " <label class=\"" + labClassSize + " control-label\">" + vals[0] + "</label>"
                            + " <div class=\"" + inpClassSize + "\">"
                            + "     <input class=\"form-control\" "
                            + "     id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "\" "
                            + "     name=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe
                            + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + vals[4] + "\" "
                            + "     type=\"" + tipe + "\" value=\"" + (realVal == null ? "" : realVal) + "\" "
                            + "     " + (en ? "" : "disabled") + ">"
                            + "     <span style=\"display:none\" "
                            + "     id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "icon\" "
                            + "     class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback\" "
                            + "     aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>"
                            + " </div>"
                            + "</div>");
                }
            } else if (vals[2].toString().equals("datetime-local")) {
                out.println(""
                        + "<div id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "div\" "
                        + "class=\"form-group\">"
                        + " <label class=\"" + labClassSize + " control-label\">" + vals[0] + "</label>"
                        + " <div class=\"" + inpClassSize + "\">"
                        + "     <input class=\"form-control\" id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "\" "
                        + "     name=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe
                        + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + vals[4] + "\" "
                        + "     type=\"" + tipe + "\" "
                        + "     value=\"" + (realVal == null ? "" : realVal.toString().replace(" ", "T")) + "\" "
                        + "     " + (en ? "" : "disabled") + ">"
                        + "     <span style=\"display:none\" "
                        + "     id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "icon\" "
                        + "     class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback\" "
                        + "     aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>"
                        + " </div>"
                        + "</div>");
            } else if (vals[2].toString().equals("select")) {
                out.println(""
                        + "<div id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "div\" "
                        + "class=\"form-group\">"
                        + " <label class=\"" + labClassSize + " control-label\">" + vals[0] + "</label>"
                        + " <div class=\"" + inpClassSize + "\">"
                        + "     <select class=\"form-control\" id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "\" "
                        + "     name=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe
                        + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + vals[4] + "\" "
                        + "     " + (en ? "" : "disabled") + ">");
                out.println("<option value=\"\">- Select -</option>");
                if (vals[5] != null) {
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("../Main/SetConn.jsp").include(request, response);
                    Connection conn = (Connection) request.getAttribute("SQLConnection");

                    if (conn != null) {
                        String colRefs[] = vals[5].toString().split(Character.toString((char) 28));
                        List<Object[]> dataRef = this.getDataRef(conn.getMySQLConn(), colRefs);
                        Object v = realVal == null ? "" : realVal;
                        for (Object[] data : dataRef) {
                            out.println("<option value=\"" + data[0] + "\" " + (v.equals(data[0]) ? "selected" : "") + ">"
                                    + "" + data[1] + "</option>");
                        }

                        if (conn.getMySQLConn() != null) {
                            conn.getMySQLConn().close();
                        }
                    }
                } else if (vals[3] != null) {
                    String valsEnum[] = vals[3].toString().split(Character.toString((char) 28));
                    Object val = realVal == null ? "" : realVal;
                    for (String v : valsEnum) {
                        out.println("<option value=\"" + v + "\" " + (val.equals(v) ? "selected" : "") + ">"
                                + "" + v + "</option>");
                    }
                }
                out.println("     </select>"
                        + "     <span style=\"display:none\" "
                        + "     id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "icon\" "
                        + "     class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback\" "
                        + "     aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>"
                        + " </div>"
                        + "</div>");
            } else if (vals[2].toString().equals("number")) {
                double step = vals[3].toString().equals("int") ? 1 : vals[3].toString().equals("double") ? 0.01 : 1;
                out.println(""
                        + "<div id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "div\" "
                        + "class=\"form-group\">"
                        + " <label class=\"" + labClassSize + " control-label\">" + vals[0] + "</label>"
                        + " <div class=\"" + inpClassSize + "\">"
                        + "    <input class=\"form-control\" id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "\" "
                        + "     name=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe
                        + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + vals[4] + "\" "
                        + "     type=\"" + vals[2] + "\" value=\"" + (realVal == null ? "" : realVal) + "\" "
                        + "     " + (en ? "" : "disabled") + " step=\"" + step + "\">"
                        + "     <span style=\"display:none\" "
                        + "     id=\"" + key + (Character.toString((char) 28)) + tipe + "icon\" "
                        + "     class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback\" "
                        + "     aria-hidden=\"tru\"></span>"
                        + " </div>"
                        + "</div>");
            }
        }
    %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="<%= labClassSizeOffset%> <%= inpClassSize%>">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="cekInput()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> <%= mode%>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" onclick="cleanField()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span> Bersihkan
            </button>
            <button id="SubmitFormHandle" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" style="display: none;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span> Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="MainTab" value="<%= request.getAttribute("MainTab")%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="FormMode" value="<%= request.getAttribute("FormMode")%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Master" value="<%= request.getAttribute("Master")%>">
    <%
        String id = (String) request.getParameter("id");
        if (id != null) {
    %>
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<%= request.getParameter("id")%>">
    <%
        }
    %>
</form>
```

Comment: Probably because you're using a `javax.xml` class for creating the Base64 value.

Answer (score 0):

[`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) is a strange choice for generating base64 represenation of your binary data. Please show some more of your JSP - your *doctype* might be generated elsewhere.

Give [Commons-Codec Base64](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) implementation a try:

```
String b64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(imageInByteArray);
```

Comment: Since the OP's code is working with streams, the Base64 streams in the same Commons Codec package may come in handy.

Comment: I used that because i dont want to add more library on my web application... Is there any other way to do it without using external library? And about the doctype, it's so strange that it actually doesn't always showed up inside the base64 image, my 2nd image shows that it showed up inside an option tag... So i think it has smthing to do with page limit maybe?

Comment: so share more of your code - as I wrote - DatatypeConverter is just a strange choice - but working nontheless probably

Comment: I somehow found the issue of it, it seems like it has something to do with the HttpServletResponse (out variable at jsp). When i change the out.println into out.print, the page seems to displays smoothly. But im not sure if that's the real cause though... Might check on another posibilities...

Comment: Your code shows no doctype and no <html> and not even a <body> f it's own?! You might want to add it and recheck.

Comment: Yeah that was 1 of the 5 pages that i include... i used mvc technique here, so the whole html tag is on the first main page, then i include this form page for inputting data... As u can see at the images i put, the main page was main.jsp with suburl callForm...